# How to change previously pressed UIButton label in UITableViewCell in OBJECTIVE C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableview with one button (for play/pause) with two textfields.
while click on play for cell1..the button text is play and the song is playing.

but I want to change the button text from play to pause while click on cell2 or any other cell.

Once the button labeled "Play" is pressed it changes to "Pause" and audio is played, and if another button is pressed in other cell the previous cell button SHOULD changes its label to "Play".

It means I want to change the button text/images depending on the play/pause as we see on our music player..Please help

I have written this. Please let me what to do next:

Blockquote

========Updated answer:

```
- (IBAction)playCallBack:(id)sender { 
    UIButton *clickedBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableView indexPathForCell: 
   (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"indexpath %ld",(long)indexPath.row);


if (_playBtn != nil && _playBtn != (UIButton*)sender) {
    [_playBtn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
     }
    if (!player)
    {

    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:@"iphone_6_original" ofType:@"mp3"];  
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];  
    player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];  
   [player setDelegate:self];
   [player prepareToPlay];
   }

    if(_playBtn == clickedBtn)
   {
    if ([player isPlaying])
    {
    [clickedBtn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [player pause];
    }

else
    {
    [clickedBtn setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [player play];            
   }
   }

else
    {
    if ([player isPlaying]) {
    player.currentTime = 0;
    [player play];
    [clickedBtn setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

else{
   [player play];
   [clickedBtn setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   }
   _playBtn = (UIButton*)sender;
   [_tableView reloadData];    
    }
```

Comment: Ever heard of didSelectRow ? :)

Comment: you can define a property in your ViewController and change the cell button text according to that property, using tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @IOS Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet completely..the code you have suggested changes both of the cell's button to pause..and also the song get stopped..

But I want to implement...when I will click on the play button of the next cell, the previously played button will get pause and the current button will be at play..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the answer and move it into an actual answer; highlight the difference between your answer and the accepted answer.. If it is identical to one of the answers below please just delete it and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new `UIButton`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *currentButton;
```

Then in action method

```
- (IBAction)playCallBack:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"indexpath %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    UIButton *clickedBtn = (UIButton*)sender;

    if (self.currentButton != nil && self.currentButton != clickedBtn) {
        [self.currentButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if (!player)
    {

        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone_6_original" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];
        player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player prepareToPlay];

    }


    if(self.currentButton == clickedBtn){
        if ([player isPlaying])
        {
            [sender setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [player pause];
        }
        else
        {
            [player play];
            [sender setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }else{
        if ([player isPlaying]) {
            [player pause];
        }

        player.currentTime = 0;
        [player play];
    }

    self.currentButton = (UIButton*)sender;
}
```

Like this you can maintain previous click button and change it according to your requirment when click on another button

Comment: Thank you for your answer..But it changes both the clicked button and the previously clicked button to pause while I click on the play on the second cell..and also the song get paused by this click.

Comment: Because your logic for player is not right you have to change logic for that

Comment: what to do then?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)playCallBack:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"indexpath %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    if (!player)
    {

        NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone_6_original" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];
        player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player prepareToPlay];

    }
    if (![player isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player play];
    }
    else
    {
        [player pause];
        [sender setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

[tableview reloadData];
}
```

if you reload when a button is pressed. and get also current index then

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *tableViewIdentifier=@"cell";
        TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableViewIdentifier];

        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableViewIdentifier];
        }

        cell.musicName.text=[musicList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.singer.text=[singerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.duration.text=[durationList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(currentIndex==indexpath.row)
         {
//do
           }
        else
       {
        //or change anything
         }
        [cell.playBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playCallBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return  cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: I want to change the button text depending on the click on the play of another cell

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.